# How to create and handle events in standard C++ in both Borland and VC++?

Tags: c++, events

Googling didn't provide me any good resource.

How to create and handle events in standard C++ in both Borland and VC++? Not in Win32SDK.

For example, handling key-press events in standard C++ console applications.

Please give me some example to get started with.

Also, please provide me with web-links that discuss about events in standard C++ in detail?

Moreover, if it is not possible to handle events in standard C++, explain why.

I found [this link](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/events/article.php/c4075) that doesn't explain the code at all.

Comment: Whilst this is a topic that interests me, I don't think this really goes on SO, if you're just asking for broad knowledge. You'll probably be told to just Google it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2k0a7d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Josh Googling didn't provide me any good resource.

Comment: What kind of events? What would generate these events? Do you mean just a general event generation/handling system?

Comment: @clamp, For example, handling key-press events in standard C++ console applications.

Comment: @Gordon Simpson, does this work in any C++ compiler? I guess no.

Comment: Since input in C++ is line buffered, and not keypress based, you need to resort to some OS API.

Comment: @ PlasmaHH, can you post any link in favor of your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can't do this in standard C++ (there are operating systems that don't event know the concept of a console or terminal), so you need to rely on some operating system API.

On Windows, you could use [`GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ReadConsoleInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You don't need a special compiler to use these. There's also good [tutorials](http://benryves.com/tutorials/winconsole/3) with examples out there.

If you want to be independent of the operating system, you can use a library like [curses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) that abstract from the different underlying mechanisms.

Comment: So, in standard C++ I always need to use polling? What is the alternative of polling?

Comment: @Saqib: For what do you want to poll? You simply can't do something like handling key presses. There are no alternatives apart from using OS-specific APIs or a library like curses or ncurses that unifies access to those.

Comment: I want to poll Keypressing. When I press an arrow key in a keyboard, a character will move on the console screen to a specific direction.

Comment: @Saqib: Not possible in standard C++. Use the WinAPI functions I referred to in my answer.

Comment: What did programmers do to achive this during the time of DOS?

Comment: @Saqib: Use DOS's API, I suppose. Or access hardware directly, which is no longer possible.